# Xcode 9.4.1: Value of type 'String' has no member 'setValue'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I'm learning Swift from a Udemy tutorial that shows how to make a chat app using a Firebase database. For my own learning and as a quick reference guide, I typed the code in a single .swift file to get a quick overview of the entire app and practice debugging. However, I have one more compiler error saying that the constant 'messagesDB' doesn't have a member 'setValue'. I'm assuming that messagesDB being an instance of class 'Database' would have access to the setValue() instance method. What do you think I'm missing in order to silence this error? Does it have something to do with the way the functions are declared?

Both class Auth and Database are arbitrary classes to mimic Firebase, so that the rest of the code could be displayed without a bunch of errors, thus giving me a single file to see how things work.

```
class Auth {

    var currentUser: String = ""

    func auth() -> Self { return self }

}

class Database {

    func setValue() -> Self { return self }
    func database() -> Self { return self }
    func reference() -> Self { return self }
    func child(_ someString: String) -> String {
        print(someString)
    }

}

class ChatViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var messageTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var sendButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func sendPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        messageTextfield.endEditing(true)

        messageTextfield.isEnabled = false
        sendButton.isEnabled = false

        let messagesDB = Database().database().reference().child("Messages")
        let messageDictionary = ["Sender": Auth().auth().currentUser, "MessageBody": messageTextfield.text!] as [String : Any]

        messagesDB.setValue(messageDictionary) {  //ERROR: Value of type 'String' has no member 'setValue'
            (error, reference) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                print("Message saved successfully!")
                self.messageTextfield.isEnabled = true
                self.sendButton.isEnabled = true
                self.messageTextfield.text = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At least you probably mean `..."MessageBody": messageTextfield.text!]`

Comment: Thanks! I made an edit of that missing piece. Unfortunately, still have an error.

Answer (score 0):

the `child` method returns a `String` and not a `Database` instance, hence the error message.

create the database instance first and then use it where needed:

```
let messagesDB = Database()
.
.
messagesDB.setValue(...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I made the change in Playground, but now the error says 'Argument passed to call that takes no arguments'. I tried modifying the setValue() method by including a parameter that is of the same type as messageDictionary, but no luck. Would you mind trying it in Playground and seeing what you'd do to silence the error? It can be anything, since it's just arbitrary code.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, your messageDB constant it's being set equals to the function "child" that returns a string, that's why it's telling you that "string" doesn't has no member setValue, so you should just set your messageDB to Database().database().reference()

Comment: I appreciate the response. I tried this using Playground, but the error changed to 'Argument passed to call that takes no arguments'. So, then I modified setValue to have a parameter of the same type as messageDictionary, but then it said 'Extra argument in call'. I know this code is arbitrary, but would you mind tinkering with it in Playground to see how you would silence the error? Thanks!

Comment: @JCoder I really don't see the point of playing with that code in a playground, your missing a lot of code to really mimic the firebase classes, but you can try this link from firebase itself https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/#0 it's really well explained and I think you'll get the hang of how everything works with firebase, if you have a repository with your code I'll be happy to contribute if you have any issues

Comment: Thank you for the link. Lol, yeah I figured my code is nonsensical. I've just been getting the hang of programming in general, and how functions and class instances work, which have been a tough concept for me to grasp.